# Best practice for nested jMockit mocks

Tags: jmockit

I have a codestyle issue with jMockit. I want to test the isReadOnly-Method in a Controller-Class and it works fine. But do I have to nest these mockUps or is there a better way? Btw. the user does not have an setController().

```
@Test
public void testIsReadOnly() {
    ExamplePanelController exampleController = new ExamplePanelController ();

    new MockUp<Environment>() {

        @Mock
        public User getUser() {

            new MockUp<User>() {

                @Mock
                public boolean isController() {
                    return true;
                }

            };
            return new User();
        }
    };

    assertFalse(exampleController.isReadOnly());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No, mock-ups should not be applied from the execution of `@Mock` methods in other mock-ups. Mock-ups are meant to be applied (by instantiation) only from test classes directly, either in @Test methods or in @Before/@BeforeClass methods.